# Masked input plugin returning `undefined is not a function`

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) is an example of masked input plug in. The demo is looking good so i want to try it out the problem is i am getting error in line

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#comp_id").mask("99-9999-999");
});
```

i Copied the `maskedinput.js` from the link and i also have a `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: what error, it's a **BIG** word?

Comment: is there any other error in your browser console

Comment: @ArunPJohny No other error just that one line it says `undefined is not a function` in the line `$("#comp_id").mask("99-9999-999");` i am wondering because i have the 2 needed component for that plugin

Comment: Do you have the maskedinput.js file locally or you load it from github? Github is not a CDN.

Comment: That's a cool plugin, actually. Works as intended from the code you provided. Check your console. http://jsfiddle.net/xdpqspv1/